# finding a solution for a PDE equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lyapunov-functions

I am going to find a solution for the following PDE:
$\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\frac{e^{-t}x}{1+x^{2n}}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}\le 0$

we should have $V(t,0)=0$ , $ V(t,x)\leq \eta_2(x)$ and $V(t,x)\ge {\eta }_1(x)\textit{}$. In addition $t>0$ and for all $x\neq0$ we should have $\eta_1>0$ and $\eta_2>0$. Applying the method of characteristic is failing. Morover, the method of sepration cannot give any solution. I will be grateful if someone help me.

Comment: This seems like the perfect set up for a viscosity solution of a Hamilton-Jacobi type equation, see this paper https://bit.ly/2L1em1X

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure that separation of variables doesn't give a solution. Let $V(t,x)=X(x)\,T(t),$ and denote time derivatives with dots and spatial derivatives with primes. Then the PDE (using equality) becomes
\begin{align*}
X'T\frac{e^{-t}x}{1+x^{2n}}+X\dot{T}&=0 \\
X'T\frac{e^{-t}x}{1+x^{2n}}&=-X\dot{T} \\
\frac{xX'}{(1+x^{2n})X}&=-\frac{e^t\,\dot{T}}{T}=k\\
xX'&=k(1+x^{2n})X\\
\dot{T}&=-ke^{-t}\,T.
\end{align*}
The spatial equation yields
$$X(x)= c_1\, x^k\,e^{\frac{kx^{2 n}}{2 n}},$$
and the temporal equation yields
$$T(t)= c_2\,e^{k\,e^{-t}}.$$
The final solution, then, would be (combining the constants into one constant $C$)
$$V(t,x)=C\,x^k\,e^{\frac{kx^{2 n}}{2 n}}\,e^{k\,e^{-t}}=C\,x^k\,\exp\left(\frac{kx^{2 n}}{2 n}+k\,e^{-t}\right). $$
We can see that $V(t,0)=0.$
As for $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2,$ you would need to type those up for us to see if this solution satisfies those constraints. Hopefully, this will get you started.